# Module compiled with Swift 4.2.1 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.0.1 compiler

Tags: swift, genexus

I've been researching this error, found some similar problems but have not found the solution to the problem I have. I am using Genexus 16 Update 4 on a Windows system to develop an iPad app, generating a Swift code for my Mac. When I access my XCode 10.2.1 and give a Build in code, it generates the following error: "Module compiled with Swift 4.2.1 can not be imported by the Swift 5.0.1 compiler ". What should I do with Genexus to solve this problem?

I already delete the directory from the Genexus environment, delete the directory where the app's Workspace was but the error still happens.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have updated the modules: Knowledge Manager -> Manage Module Reference. Gx does not update them automatically when changing the product version, so what you compile does not take changes. Tell me how you do with it!